# difference between RUN cd and WORKDIR in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker

In terms of the way Docker works, is there any difference between `RUN cd /` and `WORKDIR /` inside a Dockerfile?

Comment: "_It is to mention that WORKDIR / gives me errors_" : What errors?

Comment: It probably depends on your base Docker image and the other parts of your Dockerfile. For example, I have `FROM ubuntu:18.04` and `WORKDIR /` and it works OK. You need to help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: okay thanks ... it's part of another server, it's a bit complicated but I don't know why cd / works but WORKDIR / results in weird errors. I edited my question.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`WORKDIR /` changes the working directory for future commands.
`RUN cd /` has no impact on the subsequent RUNs.

Each `RUN` command runs in a new shell and a new environment (and technically a new container, though you won't usually notice this).  The `ENV` and `WORKDIR` directives before it affect how it starts up.  If you have a `RUN` step that just changes directories, that will get lost when the shell exits, and the next step will start in the most recent `WORKDIR` of the image.

```sh
FROM busybox
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN pwd       # /tmp

RUN cd /      # no effect, resets after end of RUN line
RUN pwd       # still /tmp

WORKDIR /
RUN pwd       # /

RUN cd /tmp && pwd  # /tmp
RUN pwd       # /
```

(For the same reason, `RUN export` doesn't do anything that outlives the current Dockerfile instructions, and `RUN .` or the non-standard `RUN source` won't cause environment variables to be set.)

Comment: “_Does absolutely nothing_” **to the subsequent `RUN`s, not the current one.**